# xsl wildcard match to exclude itself

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

In case of `Child`s with duplicate values in `Identifier` element I would like to create new element `create_duplicate`, but I do no want to match against current node itself. Currently `//Identifier/text()` matches also to itself. Is there a way to exclude it and only match against all other `Child/Identifier`s?

XML:

```
<Document>
    <List>
        <Child>
            <Identifier>19961202</Identifier>
        </Child>
        <Child>
            <Identifier>19961203</Identifier>
        </Child>
    </List>
    <WebResponse>
        <Product>
            <WebIdentifier>19961202</WebIdentifier>
        </Product>
        <Product>
            <WebIdentifier>19961203</WebIdentifier>
        </Product>
    </WebResponse>
</Document>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes"></xsl:output>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Child">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"></xsl:apply-templates>
            <operation>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="Identifier/text() = //Identifier/text()">
                        <xsl:value-of select="'create_duplicate'"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="Identifier/text() = //WebIdentifier/text()">
                                <xsl:value-of select="'update'"/>
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:otherwise>
                                <xsl:value-of select="'create'"/>
                            </xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:choose>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </operation>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result:

```
<Document>
   <List>
      <Child>
         <Identifier>19961202</Identifier>
         <!-- I would expect 'update' here as it should skip itself-->
         <operation>create_duplicate</operation>
      </Child>
      <Child>
         <Identifier>19961203</Identifier>
         <!-- I would expect 'update' here as it should skip itself-->
         <operation>create_duplicate</operation>
      </Child>
   </List>
   <WebResponse>
      <Product>
         <WebIdentifier>19961202</WebIdentifier>
      </Product>
      <Product>
         <WebIdentifier>19961203</WebIdentifier>
      </Product>
   </WebResponse>
</Document>
```

Comment: Have you considered grouping the `List/Child` by `Identifier` with `<xsl:for-each-group select="List/Child" group-by="Identifier">`? Then use a key to reference the `Product` by `WebIdentifier`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you can group and then check if there is a cross-reference or not with a key:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">
  
  <xsl:template match="Document/List">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="Child" group-by="Identifier">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="Child[key('webid', Identifier)]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <operation>{if (position() eq 1) then 'update' else 'duplicate'}</operation>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="Child[not(key('webid', Identifier))]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <operation>{if (position() eq 1) then 'create' else 'duplicate'}</operation>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  
  <xsl:key name="webid" match="Product" use="WebIdentifier"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Or use two keys, one for the "grouping", the second for the cross-reference check:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">
  
  <xsl:key name="id" match="Child" use="Identifier"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="Child[. is key('id', Identifier)[1]][key('webid', Identifier)]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <operation>update</operation>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="Child[not(. is key('id', Identifier)[1])][key('webid', Identifier)]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <operation>duplicate</operation>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Child[. is key('id', Identifier)[1]][not(key('webid', Identifier))]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <operation>create</operation>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="Child[not(. is key('id', Identifier)[1])][not(key('webid', Identifier))]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <operation>duplicate</operation>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  
  <xsl:key name="webid" match="Product" use="WebIdentifier"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
```

Comment: This may be the way to go, but unfortunately question is about ```xslt-2.0```, thus ```xsl:mode``` is not available.

Comment: I just used that to focus on the main code to solve the problem raised in the question, you can of course replace the `xsl:mode` declaration with the identity template `<xsl:template match="@* | node()"><xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/></xsl:copy></xsl:template>`. And in the first example you would also need to replace the inline text `{}` templates with `xsl:value-of`.

Comment: Thanks! This solution is quite elegant, but currently in your solution if ```Identifier```s are same, then ```operation``` is ```duplicate``` only in second ```Child``` . As I want to match all to all, then ```operation``` should be ```duplicate``` in both.

Comment: @Moontego, perhaps edit the question with some more sample data showing the input variations and wanted result. I couldn't infer from the sample what the result should be, as you wanted to look for duplicates only for any second such match I thought the above matches that. Perhaps `key('id', Identifier)[2]` is the condition to check there are duplicates and you want to output that.